# Is there a way to have presets for your terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I do ruby on rails development and usually have three different tabs set up in my terminal; one for running tests, one for editing code and running commands, and one to run the rails server. It is not a big deal to set this up when I begin working, but it would be much cooler if I could just open the terminal and have everything already set up the way I like it (3 tabs all cd to the correct directory with the correct version of rails set in rvm). Is there a way to just take a snapshot of a terminal set up and hav it just open up like that all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean gnome-terminal, from the man page:

```
--tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME
     Open a tab in the window with the given  profile.  More  than
     one of these options can be provided, to open several tabs .
```

Which would make a script like `~/bin/cool-terminal`:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=edit --tab-with-profile=run ...
```

with some scripts to put in the profiles like

```
 $ cat ~/bin/editor-tab
 #!/bin/sh
 chdir source_directory
 ...
 exec $SHELL
```

Not exactly like taking a snapshot, but it can be done.